# What does Model View ViewModel / Knockout solve?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I was reading someone's code where I came across Knockout and MVVM. I did some reading on both topics, but I'm still confused as to what problems they really solve, most likely because I just haven't built applications large enough to come across the problems that this framework/architecture solves.

I spent some time to understand this sample code -- http://knockoutjs.com/img/homepage-example.png -- from the Knockout home page. I was hoping if someone could explain to me what the same code would look like if Knockout were not used, and how that could be problematic.

(SO may not be the right platform for this question, so please let me know if there's some other Exchange that's more appropriate).

Thanks!

Comment: I think the only thing I would like as an answer to this question (that's put on hold as too broad) is to see what the above code sample would look like without Knockout and a few lines explaining why the same code without Knockout may not be favored in big applications. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**From 10,000 Feet**

Knockout provides two-way data-binding between a *view* written in HTML and corresponding properties and functions on a *viewmodel* written in JavaScript.

Imagine you have an HTML view called **contacts.html** and a JavaScript viewmodel called **contacts.js**.  Those two together would make a *module*, and Knockout would be the glue that binds them together.

MVVM stands for Model View ViewModel.  I addressed the latter two above.  The *model* is simply a JavaScript representation of a particular corner of your world, say, in this case, a **Contact**.

So, bringing together the above, we might have (in terms of directory structure):

- models\contact.js
- views\contact.html
- viewmodels\contact.js

You might instantiate your model inside your viewmodel, and then bind your view to the viewmodel using Knockout.

MVVM simply provides for a great way to separate concerns and maximize reuse.  As an example of reuse, you could bind your contacts view to many different contact viewmodels, depending on context.  The context could be the size of the client device, a user's authorization profile, a "community" versus a "premium" version of your application, and so on.

Modifying by improvement any of the components of MVVM can be done in relative isolation without adversely affecting the application as whole.  Hence the value of separating concerns.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks! That clarified quite a lot of things. But I was also hoping to see a before/after code that would help me better understand how Knockout does what you mentioned (code reuse, separate logic, etc).  Thanks, again.

Comment: @Shobit Yes, that would be quite involved, and may be why your question was put on hold.  I can tell you textually: Without Knockout (at least until ES6 arrives), there would be no elegant way to bind a view to a viewmodel.  You would have to write all of that binding in the viewmodel itself, accessing DOM elements, attaching listeners, etc., using JavaScript.  In other words, you would lose the power of _declarative_.  In the case of Knockout, you would lose `data-bind`.